# Json parsing - JSONArray to JSONObject in JAVA

Tags: java, json, json-simple

**Item.java**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
private String value;
private String type;
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String toString() {
    json.put(value, type);
    return json.toString();
  }
```

**Bean.java**

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    items=new JSONArray();
}


public void add() throws ParseException {   
    items.add(new Item());   
}

public void remove(Item item) {
    items.remove(item);
}

public void save() {
    System.out.println("JsonSchema "+items);
}

public JSONArray getItems() {  
    return items;
}
```

While retrieving **json** from Sample.java in Bean.java -  I get the output of this format -

```
[{"id":"number"},{"name":"text"},{"type":"number"}]
```

I want to convert this to JSONObject of below format using JsonSimple library-

```
{"id":"number","name":"text","type":"number"} //convert to this format
```

I am just a beginner. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You made an arrray of objects, but you need 1 object with attributes.

Comment: You're not showing what is Sample.java here. If Sample.java holds the responsibility to print a sample Item, you may just get the first item from JSONArray and print the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating with JSONArray. You need to instantiate with JSONObject

```
items=new JSONObject();
```

Also you need to use the put method instead of add method

```
items.put("item1", new item());
```

[See more here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear but it seems you dont want an Array .
The output you are getting is an Array as you are explicitly serializing into an Array . If you dont want an Array then make a Java POJO to hold all the attributes needed and serialize that. [ ] represents an array in Json

Example what could be done

```
class POJO {
attribute 1;
attribute 2;
attribute 3;
}
```

and serialize an Object of this POJO class